# how to send UDP datagram larger than system buffer?

Tags: c, sockets, udp, buffer

can any body here tell me how to send datagram larger than system buffer supplied to UDP socket in order to test the MSG_TRANC in C

and how i can get the size of the socket buffer  ?

Comment: You cannot send UDP packets larger than the socket buffer. (the kernel has no room for it, send() would error with EMSGSIZE) You cannot receive a datagram larger than the socket buffer. (the kernel has no room for it, and would drop the packet).

Comment: but there is a flag tells you that the message was truncated

Comment: Yes. That is if you try to read a packet into _your_ buffer in the application, but _your_ buffer is not large enough. e.g. someone sent you a 1000 byte packet, and you gave a buffer of size 500 to recvmsg() , the MSG_TRUNC flag will be set, the first 500 bytes gets copied to your buffer, the other 500 bytes gets throw away.  there's many layers at work here. network card -> driver ring buffer -> kernel socket buffer -> your application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always increase the buffer size with the `setsockopt` function using the `SO_SNDBUF` flag.

Otherwise `send` (or `sendto`) will normally block.

However, I would recommend you to try and rework your protocol so the packets fit inside the send buffer. You can always reassemble the packages when received (if you have proper sequencing of them).

Comment: UDP `send(2)` would not block on message larger then `SO_SNDBUF`, it will error out with `EMSGSIZE`.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean or want to to do?
I hope you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol

Are you attempting to send a datagram with total length greater than single packet size? Or is your send buffer used in building a packet too small?

Comment: i want to test the MSG_TRUNC  assosiated with UDP socket so i must increae the buffer size of sending side so the MSG_TRUNC flag works